# JS Puppeteer: enter multiple chars atomically

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to fill an html form with puppeteer using `type`. According to the docs:

```
page.type(selector, text[, options])

...

Sends a keydown, keypress/input, and keyup event for each character in the text.
```

I have an issue with other events interfering with my typing process. How can I type my text atomically? I.e. with a single `keydown` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do, `page.keyboard.sendCharacter("text")`, which will do something akin to pasting in the text all at once. Make sure to first focus the selector you want to type into.

```
await page.focus('selector');
await page.keyboard.sendCharacter('text');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it fits your needs but if you want to avoid keyboard events you could set directly the input value

```
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("YOUR_SELECTOR").value = "Puppeteer");
```

or, if you need just one `keydown` event, you can trick Puppeteer by setting the value to "almost" what you need

```
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("YOUR_SELECTOR").value = "Puppetee");
```

and use `type` just for the last char

```
await page.type("YOUR_SELECTOR", "r");
```